# Indent Expected?

Tags: python, indentation

I'm sort of new to python and working on a small text adventure it's  been going well until now I'm currently implementing a sword system where if you have a certain size sword you can slay certain size monsters. I'm trying to code another monster encounter and I have coded the sword stuff but I'm trying to finish it off with an `else` to the `if...elif...elif` statement and even though I have it in the right indentation it still says indent expected I don't know what to do here's the code:

```
print ('you find a monster about 3/4 your size do you attack? Y/N')
yesnotwo=input()
if yesnotwo == 'Y':
    if ssword == 'Y':
        print ('armed with a small sword you charge the monster, you impale it before it can attack it has 50 gold')
        gold += 50
        print ('you now have ' + str(gold) + ' gold')
    elif msword == 'Y':
        print ('armed with a medium sword you charge the monster, you impale the monster before it can attack it has 50 gold')
        gold += 50
        print ('you now have ' + str(gold) + ' gold')
    elif lsword == 'Y':
        print ('armed with a large broadsword you charge the beast splitting it in half before it can attack you find 50 gold ')
        gold += 50
        print ('you now have ' + str(gold) + ' gold')
    else:
```

Comment: Make sure you use the same kind of indentation (i.e. space vs tab)

Comment: Also, if there really isn't any code under the `else`, you will get an indentation error.

Comment: Is this just a snippet of your code?

Comment: also when i try to run this part of the code none of this works maybe its because i have errors higher up and i will check and maybe because the if else doesnt have an else either way its being finicky

Comment: yes its a snippet and i have been using tabs as far as i can tell

Comment: Please read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces): "Spaces are the preferred indentation method. Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are, in fact, multiple things you need to know about indentation in Python:

### **Python really cares about indention.**

In other languages, indention is not necessary but only serves to improve the readability. In Python, indentation is necessary and replaces the keywords `begin / end` or `{ }` of other languages.

This is verified before the execution of the code. Therefore even if the code with the indentation error is never reached, it won't work.

### **There are different indention errors and you reading them helps a lot:**

**1. `IndentationError: expected an indented block`**

There are multiple reasons why you can have such an error, but the common reason will be:

- **You have a `:` without an indented block underneath.**

Here are two examples:

***Example 1, no indented block:***

Input:

```
if 3 != 4:
    print("usual")
else:
```

Output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 4

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

The output states that you need to have an indented block on line 4, after the `else:` statement.

***Example 2, unindented block:***

Input:

```
if 3 != 4:
print("usual")
```

Output

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("usual")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

The output states that you need to have an indented block on line 2, after the `if 3 != 4:` statement.

**2. `IndentationError: unexpected indent`**

It is important to indent blocks, but only blocks that should be indented. This error says:

**- You have an indented block without a `:` before it.**

***Example:***

Input:

```
a = 3
  a += 3
```

Output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    a += 3
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

The output states that it wasn't expecting an indented block on line 2. You should fix this by remove the indent.

**3. `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`**

- But basically it's, you are using tabs and spaces in your code.
- You don't want that.
- Remove all tabs and replaces them by four spaces.
- And configure your editor to do that automatically.
- You can get some more info [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

---

Eventually, to come back on your problem:

> I have it in the right indentation it still says indent expected I don't know what to do

Just look at the line number of the error, and fix it using the previous information.