# Interrupted shell in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

```
>>> def volume(r):
... v = (4.0/3.0) * matth.pi * r**3
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    v = (4.0/3.0) * math.pi * r**3
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

While writing a code in the Python3 interactive shell environment, at the end of some lines, such as parameters of a function, the interpreter breaks. 
Here is an example:

```
def volume(r):
    v = (4.0/3.0) * math.pi * r**3
```

and the code breaks at the end of this line, after hitting the enter.
Any solution to be able to continue writing the code in the interactive Python 3 shell?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? How does it break? What does it look like?

Comment: The colon was a typo, thanks.

Comment: Python's indentation heavy. See [_this other SO answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39395307/10239789).

Comment: While I am typing, there is no way to add indentation in the interactive Python 3 shell or I don't know how which is why I am asking the question to find out. After the type of the colon, it does the indentation the next line, which starts with "..." but after this line, to go to the next line, I can't or don't know how to add indentation. The OS is MacOS.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Don't inline pictures of text, there is a reason new users are forbidden from doing so. Either transcribe it, or leve them alone.

Comment: @EdwinMajnoonian the ellipsis `...` don't count as part of the indentation. In the interactive shell, you should be able to press tab or space to indent the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an indentation at the beginning of the second line. It can be 1, 2, 4 spaces or a tabulation. The important is to stay consistent.

Note also that Python3 recommends 4 spaces over tab: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code, Tabs or Spaces?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), but when trying out some code in the interpreter you can choose what is more suitable to you.